# reduce formater json to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reduce

help me solve my problem
I want to bring out this format:

```
true: 2,3,4
false: 5
```

i'm use sequelize,
I don't understand how I can correctly output json
see my code below. But it doesn't work. I added

```js
const test = {
    one: {
        'user': '2',
        'status': '1', block: {
            'ok': 'false'
        }
    },
    two: {
        'user': '3',
        'status': '1', block: {
            'ok': 'false'
        }
    },
    three: {
        'user': '4',
        'status': '1', block: {
            'ok': 'false'
        }
    },
    five: {
        'user': '5',
        'status': '0', block: {
            'ok': 'true'
        }
    }
}
const grouped = test.reduce((groups, test) => ({
    ...groups,
    [test.user]: [...(groups[test.user] || []), test.block.ok]
}), {});
const text = Object.entries(grouped).map(([key, values]) => `${key}: ${values}`).join('\n');
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
true: 5
false: 2,3,4
```

You cannot reduce the object because it is an Array prototype. You need first to transform your `test` object into the array with `Object.valaues` and group them by `true` and `false`

```js
const test = {
  one: {
    user: '2',
    status: '1',
    block: {
      ok: 'false',
    },
  },
  two: {
    user: '3',
    status: '1',
    block: {
      ok: 'false',
    },
  },
  three: {
    user: '4',
    status: '1',
    block: {
      ok: 'false',
    },
  },
  five: {
    user: '5',
    status: '0',
    block: {
      ok: 'true',
    },
  },
};
const grouped = Object.values(test).reduce(
  (groups, group) => {
    groups[group.block.ok].push(group.user);
    return groups;
  },
  { true: [], false: [] },
);
const text = Object.entries(grouped)
  .map(([key, values]) => `${key}: ${values}`)
  .join('\n');
console.log(text);
```